# TypeError: string indices must be integers in Flask

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, casting

I have being using python dictionaries for one of my tasks and this error prompted related to the below mention statements.

```
def flat(self, data, no_of_attrs):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        if len(data) == 1:
            self.flat(data[0], no_of_attrs)
        elif len(data) > 1:
            for j in data:
                self.flat(j, no_of_attrs)
        else:
            return
    #if dictionary
    else:
        if len(data)==1:
            if data['parent_id']==0 or 1:
                self.flat(self, data['children_data'], no_of_attrs)
            else:
                n_item = item(data['id'], data['parent_id'], data['name'], data['is_active'], data['position'], data['product_count'], data['path'], data['name_ar'])
```

The Error Occured related to the condition, `if data['parent_id']==0 or 1:` .

Can anybody see the issue with this and help me to solve this.

```
[{"id": 6, "parent_id": 5, "name": "Boots", "enabled": true, "position": 1,  "children_data": [],  "path": "/women/shoes/boots"}, {"id": 1523, "parent_id": 5, "name": "Flats", "enabled": true, "position": 2, "children_data": [], "path": "/women/shoes/flats"}, {"id": 16, "parent_id": 5, "name": "Ballerinas", "enabled": true,"count": 12505, "children_data": [], "path": "/women/shoes/ballerinas"}]
```

[image]

PS:- data is a dictionary

Comment: Just to point out, I think what you want to write is `if data['parent_id'] in (0, 1):`. Currently, your code will be evaluated as `(if data['parent_id'] == 0 or 1:`

Comment: can you post the sample data in your question? And post the traceback.

Comment: Yes @NChauhan , thank you! Any clue about this?

Comment: @YogeshMhaskule Updated with the required details.

Comment: From what it looks like, the `data` object is a string. Try adding some `print(data, type(data))` calls around to see what exactly the object being passed in is. Also, your function doesn't return anything. Did you mean to write `return self.flat(...)` in the recursive parts?

Comment: Hi no the data object initially comes as a dict. I checked with type as well. Returns and appends are all handled. The data argument would change in between list and dictionary. That's why I have used the first conditional statements here

Comment: @PasanChamikara Might be you get the list as data inside else statement. And you're checking the 'parent_id' inside list using if condition, actually it should be the dict. Try adding the print(data) inside else block. Why you are checking the length of data inside else statement, anyway you always get dict there!.

Comment: @YogeshMhaskule Thank you! The issue was caused due to the string objects finally being called after dictionaries and lists. Problem was solved. ;)